# Android: Using ViewPager to fill RelativeLayout from MainActivity

Tags: android, class, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, main-activity

Ok I'll first try it short. Does anyone know how I insert this class

```
public class ResultBar extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagerlayout);
   ...
```

from the MainActivity into its ViewPager layout?

Comment: Just for me to understand clear. You want to add ResultBar into your MainActivity?

Comment: yes I want to load it with the main activity into the layout

Comment: Well, was my answer useful?

Comment: I'm still testing, but yes, I could integrate it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add one activity into another activity. Android use Fragments for this functionality. You can learn few things about them [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) or [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html).

So you can convert your `ResultBar` to `Fragment`, also converting your `MainActivity` to `FragmentActivity`, its previous content to `MainActivityContentFragment` and add `ResultBarFragment` to your `MainActivity`. This is how your main activity layour could look like:

/res/layout/main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.MainActivityContentFragment
            android:id="@+id/content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment class="com.example.ResultBarFragmnt
            android:id="@+id/result_bar" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here also snippet how your ResultBarFragment could look like:

```
public class ResultBarFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagerlayout, container, false);
    }
```